Proving Mutual Absolute Continuity of two Haar Measures
The following is a theorem from Dana William's book on Crossed Products of $C^{*}$-algebras, and I don't see how he verifies part of this claim.

Let $G$ be a locally compact group with left Haar measure $\mu$ and modular function $\Delta: G \longrightarrow (0,\infty)$.  Then for all $f \in C_c(G)$ we have: $$\int_{G} f(s^{-1})\Delta(s^{-1}) \: d\mu(s) = \int_{G} f(s) \: d\mu(s).$$  Moreover, If $\nu$ is a right Haar measure given by $\nu(E) = \mu(E^{-1})$, then: $$\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}(s) = \Delta(s^{-1}), \: \: s \in G.$$

The proof of the first statement with the integrals is no issue, however he then makes the claim that $\nu \ll \mu \ll \nu$.  To begin, we observe that for any $g \in C_c(G)$: $$\int_{G} g(s) \: d\nu(s) = \int_{G} g(s^{-1}) \: d\mu(s) \implies \int_{G} f(s)\Delta(s) \: d\nu(s) = \int_{G} f(s^{-1})\Delta(s^{-1}) \: d\mu(s)$$ $$\implies \int_{G} f(s) \: d\mu(s) = \int_{G} f(s)\Delta(s) \: d\nu(s), \: \: f \in C_c(G).$$  Now, from here they just say that "if $E \subset G$ is Borel with $\nu(E)=0$, then $\mu(E) = 0$, since for any compact $K \subset E$: $$\mu(K) = \int_{G} \chi_K(s) \: d\mu(s) = \int_{G} \chi_K(s)\Delta(s) \: d\nu(s) = \int_{K} \Delta(s) \: d\nu(s)$$ $$ \leq \int_{E} \Delta(s) \: d\nu(s) = 0.$$  Hence $\mu(E)=0$ so that $\mu \ll \nu$ and analogously $\nu \ll \mu$."  I have three issues / questions.

I don't see how $\mu(E)=0$ follows, as Haar measures are compact inner regular on open subsets, not arbitrary Borel subsets $E$, so I fail to see how me knowing that $\mu(K)=0$ for all $K \subset E$ compact implies $\mu(E)=0$.

Moreover, we only showed the relation $\int_{G} f \: d\mu = \int_{G} f \Delta \: d\nu$ for $f \in C_c(G)$, whereas the equality $\int_{G} \chi_K \: d\mu = \int_{G} \chi_K \Delta \: d\nu$ is for the function $\chi_K \in L^1(G)$, but isn't necessarily continuous. I'm guessing what they are doing here is getting a decreasing sequence of open sets $U_1 \supset U_2 \supset \dots \supset K$ where $\mu(U_n \setminus K) < 1/k$ and $\nu(U_n \setminus K) < 1/k$, and applying Uryshon's lemma to get a sequence $(f_n)_n \subset C_c(G, [0,1])$ where $f_n|K \equiv 1$ and $f_n|_{U^c_n} \equiv 0$ so that $f_n \downarrow \chi_K$ pointwise $\mu,\nu$ almost everywhere, where the dominated convergence theorem gives: $$\mu(K) = \int_{G} \chi_K \: d\mu = \lim_n \int_{G} f_n \: d\mu = \lim_n \int_{G} f_n \Delta \: d\nu = \int_{G} \chi_K \Delta \: d\nu??$$  If this isn't what is going on here, I would appreciate someone explaining this to me.

Right after they say $\mu(E) = 0$, they also just state that "moreover $\int_{G} \chi_E \: d\mu = \int_G \chi_E \Delta \: d\nu$ for all $E \subset G$ Borel, so $d\mu = \Delta d\nu$."  But how do you verify this?  If I knew that $\Delta d\nu$ is a Radon measure, then knowing $\mu = \Delta d \nu$ on compacta (which from 2. I have) is sufficient by the regularity conditions, but would need to know apriori that $\Delta d\nu$ is Radon.  Namely that it's regular, but unless every open subset of $G$ is $\sigma$-compact (which I obviously don't have necessarily) then I can't just check that $\Delta d\nu$ is finite on compacta to get regularity, so I need to verify this manually.  How am I supposed to do that?


Thank you.
